# does branch created from using different version of Xcode really differ in git?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, branch

I'm not sure , this may be basic question but still asking it as I have doubt.
I have branch named "Rendering" which was created using Xcode 10 version used for code changes.

Now I created another branch named "ShadowBaking" from "Rendering" branch but used Xcode 11 beta 6 for code changes.

My question is, does "ShadowBaking" branch will have SDK from Xcode beta 6 in this branch or it does not matter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SDK isn't "in" the branch, it is a setting in the project file. Your new branch may well have a different setting for the SDK, but you can change that setting so this "does not matter" in git terms.